# If $\int f=0$ then $f=0$ a.e. with $f\geq 0$. Is it true if $f(x) = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have a doubt!

I know that if $f$ measurable and nonnegative, $\int f=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e.

And if $m(E)=0$ then $\int_{E}f=0$ (even if $f(x)=\infty$ forall $x$)

If $f(x)=\infty$ forall $x$, $f:X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $m(X)=0$ then $\int_{X}f=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e.

Can it be $f = 0$ a.e. even when $f(x) = \infty$ for all $x$ in $X$?

Comment: Yes, since $X$ has measure zero. It may sound strange, however if the space has measure zero itself then this space endowed with that measure does not have a measure theoretic interest.

Comment: In particular, if $m(X) = 0$, then *any* (syntactically valid) statement in terms of $x$ is true for a.e. $x \in X$.

Comment: When stating a result, you must put the conditions before the conclusions! This is a common error. Your title should read: "If $\int f=0$ with $f\ge 0$, then $f=0$ a.e."

Comment: What do you mean by $f(x)=\infty$? It is possible to give it a meaning, but not, I think, in the context of Lebesgue integration.